# Why ToString() method can be overridden without inheritance being involved in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, tostring

Please find the below example:

```
using System;

 class MyClass 
 {
   static int count = 0;
   int id;

   public MyClass() 
   {
     id = count;
     count++;
   }

 public override string ToString() 
 {
   return "MyClass object #" + id;
 }
}

 class Test 
 {
   static void Main() 
   {
     MyClass ob1 = new MyClass();
     MyClass ob2 = new MyClass();
     MyClass ob3 = new MyClass();
     Console.WriteLine(ob1);
     Console.WriteLine(ob2);
     Console.WriteLine(ob3);
   }
 }
```

The output from the program is shown here:

MyClass object #0
MyClass object #1
MyClass object #2

As you can see here method ToString() is overridden in the class named 'MyClass' but 'MyClass' is not derived from any class, there exists no inheritance at all. If there is no inheritance involved how 'override' can be used?

If we you change ToString() to any other method Name say 'HelloString()' as in the below Code snippet:

```
 public class Program
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        MyClass ob1 = new MyClass();
        MyClass ob2 = new MyClass();
        MyClass ob3 = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine(ob1);
        Console.WriteLine(ob2);
        Console.WriteLine(ob3);
    }
}

 class MyClass 
 {
   static int count = 0;
   int id;

   public MyClass() 
   {
     id = count;
     count++;
   }

 public override string HelloString() 
 {
   return "MyClass object #" + id;
 }
}
```

Compiler throws error: 'no suitable method found to override'

Why this special behavior with 'ToString()' method?

Comment: You are inheriting from [object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx.

> Object class is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.
>
> Languages typically do not require a class to declare inheritance from
> Object because the inheritance is implicit.
>
> Because all classes in the .NET Framework are derived from Object, every method defined in the Object class is available in all objects in the system. Derived classes can and do override some of these methods, including:
>
> - Equals - Supports comparisons between objects.
> - Finalize - Performs cleanup operations before an object is
>   automatically reclaimed.
> - GetHashCode - Generates a number corresponding to the value of the
>   object to support the use of a hash table.
> - ToString - Manufactures a human-readable text string that describes
>   an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

It's derived from Object, which is where that method is defined.

Answer (score 0):

every type is derived from object in oop and thats where ToString() method is defined and its virtual so you can override it

Answer (score 0):

`Object` has a `ToString()` method. Every class inherits from `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ToString` method *is* inherited!

There is one thing that all classes implicitly inherit from. And structs kind of inherit from it as well. Through boxing, you can assign a struct to that type of variable.

Can you guess what it is?

> It's `Object`!

This class contains methods like `ToString`, `GetHashCode`, `Equals` that you can override to define your own behaviour of your object. You can see more here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Really, your MyClass is derived from Object class. If you use

```
class MyClass : Object
```

the result is the same.